# How to expose salesforce documents to google search

Tags: document, google

I am just wondering is there any chance to expose the documents that are stored under Documents tab in salesforce to Google search.

In salesforce i am storing few docs under Documents tab

[image]

I am looking for an approach to find these documents by doing some search on any search engines like google